# Flume changing txt files to binaries

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume, spool

I am spooling directory with Flume and uploading files into hdfs. These are txt/csv files, and I want them in that format in hdfs. But Flume is loading them as binary files...

Here is my config:

```
tier1.sources  = source1
tier1.channels = channel1
tier1.sinks    = sink1

tier1.sources.source1.type     = spooldir
tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
tier1.sources.source1.spoolDir = /var/data
tier1.sources.source1.fileHeader = false
tier1.sources.source1.deletePolicy = immediate
tier1.channels.channel1.type   = memory
tier1.sinks.sink1.type         = hdfs
tier1.sinks.sink1.channel      = channel1
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = /user/hdfs/%y-%m-%d/
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 30

tier1.channels.channel1.capacity = 100
```

What should I change to make Flume load txt files as txt files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should solve your problem:

> tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
>
> tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

Comment: That not solve this problem anyway the lines in telnet is saved in binary files on HDFS.